# How to get internal calls Calldata in solidity?

Tags: solidity, evm, assembly, calldata

**How to get signature of setA() when user is calling setB() for below code snippet ?**

```
contract Sig {

  function setA() public {
    // How to get function signature of `setA()` at this location while calling through `setB()` in runtime
  }

  function setB() public {
    setA();
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `keccak256` function to get the signature of `setA()` in the `setB()` function, like this:

```
function setA() public {
    // code here
}

function setB() public {
    bytes4 signature = bytes4(keccak256("setA()"));
    setA();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the string "setA()" to the keccak256() function to get the function signature of setA(). Use `abi.encodeWithSignature()` to encode the function signature & returns the bytes4 representation of the function signature.

```
function setA() public {
    bytes4 signature = keccak256(abi.encodeWithSignature("setA()"));
    // use the signature variable as needed
}

function setB() public {
    setA();
}
```